# How can I update post category relationship when a category with its subcategories is deleted in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

In my blog system I have many-to-many relationship. I have three tables viz. tb_categories, tb_posts and tb_post_cat_relationships. These are given below -

tb_categories -

[image]

tb_posts -

[image]

tb_post_cat_relationships -

[image]

You can understand the relationship between these three tables. Now what happens when a category is deleted then post falling under it will be assigned to Uncategorized (its id is -1 and it is not present in the tb_categories table). And if a parent category is deleted then all its subcategories are also deleted but all the posts falling in parent and children categories will be associated to Uncategorized i.e. -1 id.

Here problem starts for me. If different posts are associated to these parent and child categories then its ok - i update all post to -1 corresponding to those categories ids. But if a single post is associated to several categories and their children categories then a lot of duplicate rows are created because a single common post with id suppose 1 could be associated to category 1 and its subcategories 2, 3, 4 etc. So there will be 4 rows created with duplicate data like

[image]

Because I deleted parent category Web Development so its child category PHP is also deleted and consequently the post belonging to these both category now assigned to -1 Uncategorized category.

This is the issue. I want only single unique row for a post. Since now post sharing the multiple categories and assigned to Uncategorized -1 so there should be only one row like this -

[image]

How can i sort out this issue? My PHP code is given below -

When I delete the category this code is called -

```
    $where = $_GET['cat_id'];
    $status = $db_obj->update_post_cat_relationship($where)->delete_category($where);
```

And this is the code which updates the table and delete the categories -

```
// update post category relationship
public function update_post_cat_relationship($where)
{
    if(is_array($where) && !empty($where))
    {
        $cat_id = implode(", ", $where);

        // first update all the sub-categories
        $query = "SELECT `category_id` FROM `tb_categories` WHERE `category_parent` IN (" . $cat_id . ")";
        $rs = mysqli_query($this->con, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
            {   
                $this->update_post_cat_relationship($row['category_id']);
            }
        }

        // then update the parent category
        $query = "UPDATE `tb_post_cat_relationships` SET `cat_id` = -1 WHERE `cat_id` IN (" . $cat_id . ")";
        $rs = mysqli_query($this->con, $query);
        //$affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->con);
        if($rs)
        {
            return $this;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    elseif(!is_array($where) && !empty($where))
    {
        // first update all the sub-categories
        $query = "SELECT `category_id` FROM `tb_categories` WHERE `category_parent` = " . $where;
        $rs = mysqli_query($this->con, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
            {   
                $this->update_post_cat_relationship($row['category_id']);
            }
        }

        // then update the parent category
        $query = "UPDATE `tb_post_cat_relationships` SET `cat_id` = -1 WHERE `cat_id` = " . $where;
        $rs = mysqli_query($this->con, $query);
        //$affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->con);
        if($rs)
        {
            return $this;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// delete category and subcategories    
public function delete_category($where)
{
    if(is_array($where) && !empty($where))
    {
        $cat_id = implode(", ", $where);

        // first delete all the sub-categories
        $query = "SELECT `category_id` FROM `tb_categories` WHERE `category_parent` IN (" . $cat_id . ")";
        $rs = mysqli_query($this->con, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
            {   
                $this->delete_category($row['category_id']);
            }
        }

        // then delete the parent category
        $query = "DELETE FROM `tb_categories` WHERE `category_id` IN (" . $cat_id . ")";
        mysqli_query($this->con, $query);

        $affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->con);
        if($affected_rows)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    elseif(!is_array($where) && !empty($where))
    {
        // first delete all the sub-categories
        $query = "SELECT `category_id` FROM `tb_categories` WHERE `category_parent` = " . $where;
        $rs = mysqli_query($this->con, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs))
            {   
                $this->delete_category($row['category_id']);
            }
        }

        // then delete the parent category
        $query = "DELETE FROM `tb_categories` WHERE `category_id` = " . $where;
        mysqli_query($this->con, $query);

        $affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($this->con);
        if($affected_rows)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-foreign-keys.html) with cascade deleting. On removing it will remove relation or set NULL value.